# jQuery UI buttons set checked radio by another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery ui's `$(input).button()` to good effect, all I want to be able to do is set one of 2 radios to "checked" by something else and have the graphics update in the ui.

I'm using `$("#radio1").attr("checked",true); $("radio2").attr("checked",false);` which works fine without the jquery ui, but when `.button()` is applied, there is no appearance update (only attribute).

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Better will be, you share your implementation in jsfiddle, that will be easy to understand

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/csLZB/3/ would be it if jsfiddle was working with jq-iu

Comment: just read, you need to use `.button("refresh")`